# Tabs don't work on iPhone

Tags: css, iphone, tabs, mobile-safari

For some reason my tabs work fine on a desktop, but on my iphone I cannot click on anything within the tabs.

```
http://199.119.123.134/surety-bonds/commercial-bonds/auto_dealer_bond.htm
```

I'm stuck!  Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, but "don't work" is not enough of a problem description. What exactly goes wrong?

Comment: When viewing the page on my iphone, I cannot click anything within the tabs.  It's as if they aren't links.  The tabs themselves don't work either.